# HTML Table with different row heights

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a grid based on HTML table with the following layout.

---

### | D | B | D |

### | C | A | C |

### | D | B | D |

Where:
A: 200x200
B: 200x20
C: 20x200
D: 20x20

What is the best way to achieve this. Or should I use some other element like div to create my own grid.

**EDIT**
Each cell will have different kind of content. Some will have dropdown, some will have input with couple buttons, and C will have contents vertically flipped (90 degree). Following is the latest fiddle that I'm testing with.

`[https://jsfiddle.net/mjawaid/a3ody1wq/16/][1]`

Comment: Post the code you have so far

Comment: Table should be enough for such a grid. You need to define height and width at each cell.

Comment: I have a fiddle for that https://jsfiddle.net/mjawaid/a3ody1wq/ where 16 is the latest version at https://jsfiddle.net/mjawaid/a3ody1wq/16/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use different classes for different cells. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yrncor3a/2/

html:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="d">D</td>
      <td class="b">B</td>
      <td class="d">D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="c">C</td>
      <td class="a">A</td>
      <td class="c">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="d">D</td>
      <td class="b">B</td>
      <td class="d">D</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And CSS:

```
td{
  border: 1px solid #666;
  text-align: center;
}
.a{
  width:200px;
  height:200px
}
.b{
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}
.c{
  width: 20px;
  height: 200px;
}
.d{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This seems good. I was also trying similar but I have C cells to display content vertically. Please see my updated fiddle in question. Thanks.

Comment: I updated your html at https://jsfiddle.net/mjawaid/yrncor3a/3/ and table got messed up.

Comment: @Jawaid Could you provide a sketch of how you want it to look? (The problem is that the content of the left and right cells is too large to fit in 40px, so the cells expand.) So do you want the input and button next to each other on the same line, do you want them to be 20px high each, etc.

Comment: @TarafderAshekEElahi great thanks a lot. That's what exactly I needed.

Answer (score 8):

There are **6 possible approaches** to producing a table-like grid layout in a web document:

- Grid using HTML Tables
- Grid using CSS Absolute Positioning
- Grid using CSS Floats
- Grid using CSS2 Tables
- Grid using CSS3 Flexbox
- Grid using CSS3 Grids

---

## Grid using HTML Tables

You can establish the default dimensions of a table cell as `20 x 20` and then add two more CSS declarations to indicate where the `width` needs to be `200` and where the `height` needs to be `200`.

**Working Example:**

```css
td {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
font-size: 8px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(2),
tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(2) {
width: 200px
}

tr:nth-of-type(2) td {
height: 200px
}

tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(odd){
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>20x20</td>
<td>200x20</td>
<td>20x20</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>20x200</td>
<td>200x200</td>
<td>20x200</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>20x20</td>
<td>200x20</td>
<td>20x20</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

## Grid using CSS Absolute Positioning

To duplicate a table-like layout using CSS alone (and without using CSS tables), you can also absolutely position elements inside a relatively positioned parent element.

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
position: relative;
}

div > div {
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
font-size: 8px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

div > div:nth-of-type(n) {
top: 0;
}

div > div:nth-child(n+4) {
top: 23px;
height: 200px;
}

div > div:nth-of-type(n+7) {
top: 226px;
height: 20px;
}

div > div:nth-of-type(3n-2) {
left: 0;
}

div > div:nth-of-type(3n-1) {
left: 23px;
width: 200px;
}

div > div:nth-of-type(3n){
left: 226px;
}

div > div:nth-child(4),
div > div:nth-child(6) {
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

div > div:nth-child(5) {
line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div>20x20</div>
<div>200x20</div>
<div>20x20</div>
<div>20x200</div>
<div>200x200</div>
<div>20x200</div>
<div>20x20</div>
<div>200x20</div>
<div>20x20</div>
</div>
```

---

## Grid using CSS Floats

An alternative to CSS Absolute Positioning (which requires less fine tuning than absolute positioning, since you don't need to give the co-ordinates of each element) is to use CSS Floats.

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
display: block;
width: 252px;
height: 252px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 8px;
font-weight: bold;
}

div > div {
float: left;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
margin: 1px;
}

div:nth-of-type(3n-1) {
width: 200px;
}

div:nth-of-type(n+4):nth-of-type(-n+6) {
height: 200px;
}

div > div:nth-child(4),
div > div:nth-child(6) {
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

div:nth-of-type(5) {
line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div>20x20</div>
<div>200x20</div>
<div>20x20</div>
<div>20x200</div>
<div>200x200</div>
<div>20x200</div>
<div>20x20</div>
<div>200x20</div>
<div>20x20</div>
</div>
```

---

## Grid using CSS2 Tables

Often overlooked, CSS2 Tables can often be a superior alternative to HTML Tables.

Why? Because they only display as tables at all because of `display: table`. When you are putting together *responsive designs*, such elements can stop being tables whenever they need to display as a `block` or an `inline-block` or anything else.

HTML Tables are renowned for not playing well with smaller screen sizes. But, as you see from the example below, a CSS Table could quite easily transform itself (inside a CSS `@media` query) from a table to a vertical list or a slideshow or anything else you wanted.

**Working Example:**

```css
.table {
display: table;
font-size: 8px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
border-spacing: 1px 1px;
}

.table > div {
display: row;
}

.table > div > div {
display: table-cell;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.table > div > div:nth-of-type(2) {
width: 200px;
}

.table > div:nth-of-type(2) > div {
height: 200px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.table > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(odd) {
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">

<div>
<div>20x20</div>
<div>200x20</div>
<div>20x20</div>
</div>

<div>
<div>20x200</div>
<div>200x200</div>
<div>20x200</div>
</div>

<div>
<div>20x20</div>
<div>200x20</div>
<div>20x20</div>
</div>

</div>
```

---

## Grid using CSS3 Flexbox

We're dealing with a clearly defined grid with specific dimensions and co-ordinates here, so Flexbox is probably not the right approach.

That said, Flexbox is nothing if not a sophisticated next-generation successor to CSS Floats. So - just as you can create the table-like grid layout using floats - you can with **CSS3 Flexbox** too.

```css
div {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-content: center;
width: 252px;
height: 252px;
line-height: 20px;
font-size: 8px;
font-weight: bold;
}

div > div {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
margin: 1px;
border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

div > div:nth-of-type(3n-1) {
flex: 0 0 200px;
}

div > div:nth-of-type(n+4) {
height: 200px;
}

div > div:nth-of-type(n+7) {
height: 20px;
}

div > div:nth-of-type(4),
div > div:nth-of-type(6) {
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div>20x20</div>
<div>200x20</div>
<div>20x20</div>
<div>20x200</div>
<div>200x200</div>
<div>20x200</div>
<div>20x20</div>
<div>200x20</div>
<div>20x20</div>
</div>
```

---

## Grid using CSS3 Grids

**And finally...** the one we've all been waiting for - **CSS3 Grids**.

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 20px 200px 20px;
grid-template-rows: 20px 200px 20px;
grid-gap: 2px;
font-size: 8px;
font-weight: bold;
}

div > div {
display: block;
border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
text-align: center;
line-height: 20px;
}

div > div:nth-of-type(4),
div > div:nth-of-type(6) {
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

div > div:nth-of-type(5){
line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div>20x20</div>
<div>200x20</div>
<div>20x20</div>
<div>20x200</div>
<div>200x200</div>
<div>20x200</div>
<div>20x20</div>
<div>200x20</div>
<div>20x20</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this is a real tour de force... thanks, I'll be referring to this frequently.  Of course you don't mention the respective pros and cons, but that's for us to research no doubt.  Seeing as you are a man who knows, perhaps I could ask you the question which has led me here: I want to use a bog-standard `TABLE` (with `TR`s and `TD`s)... but I want to make the `height` of the `TD`s (and rows) **less** than required by the text content (so curtail it).  I'm beginning to surmise that this is impossible!  And that the text must all go under a `DIV` within the cell.  Is this correct?

Comment: The first thing I'd be tempted to try is experimenting with a `line-height` that was less than the `font-size`... something like the following style rule: `tr, td {height: 10px; line-height: 10px; font-size: 16px;}`

Comment: Thanks... I'd tried everything there except making the `font-size` larger. Didn't seem to work for me.  Incidentally these are long strings with `<BR>`s in them. I conclude that some tag, e.g. `P` or `DIV`, must come between `TD` and the text if you want to make cell height **smaller** than default.  Or try one of your other 5 solutions, of course.

Comment: CSS2 Tables (see above) were intended (at least in some respects) to be the next evolution of tables - more versatile than a `<table>` marked up in HTML. The take-up was never very high, but they are well-worth learning to use. Start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Introduction#CSS_tables